# Docker for windows not working after install

Tags: windows, docker, installation, hyper-v

Steps:

1. Installed Docker for windows [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) (stable)
2. Attempted to run: An error occurred, Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS.
3. Went [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled) the read
4. Made sure I have 64bit windows 10 pro and hyper-v turned on.
5. [image: Checked settings]
6. Made sure virtualization is enabled
7. Run Docker again: same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources that might help:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/bootcamp-running-windows-hardware-assisted-virtualization-and-data-execution-protection-must-be-enabled-in-the-bios/23519/2
- https://forums.docker.com/t/mobylinuxvm-failed-to-start/15175

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help.  But these links are specific to OSX or Linux with windows boot.  But my core OS is already windows.  I boot up and virtualization is enabled, hyper-v is enabled but docker fails.